# the PostAcquireRequestState event cached but “Context.user” is null

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, httpmodule

I have an asp.net website. I used form Authentication for authenticate users. I used an httpmodule in my project. This module works fine in visual studio development server. But when I hosted it on IIS7, the PostAcquireRequestState event cached but “Context.user” is null even the user is authenticated. 
Any Idea??...

Answer (score 0):

I Use this config for Custom Module:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
      <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" preCondition=""/>
      <add name="MyModule" type="MyModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

and it work fine on iis

Answer (score 0):

@Alireza, It's most likely that the pipeline mode of your application pool is set to integrated. You need to change it to classic and your problem would be solved then.